# split string in substring using a string delimiter

Tags: c#, string, winforms, split

I've a string message that could be like

```
"TRX00  abcd 20150921    "
```

or like (n) times that string, I.e.

```
"TRX00  abcd 20150921    TRX00  abcd 20150921    TRX00  abcd 20150921    "
```

etc..

How can I split that string in (n) strings using `"TRX"` at the beginning of each substring like a delimiter?

I want to take the delimiter `"TRX"` in the substring.

I've done the following but it's doesn't work well..

```
string msg = "TRX00  abcd 20150921    TRX00  abcd 20150921    TRX00  abcd 20150921    ";

string[] _msg;
string pattern = "(TRX)";
string msg2 = "";

if(msg.Contains("TRX"))
{
    _msg = Regex.Split(msg, pattern);

    foreach (string ok in _msg)
    {
        msg2 = ok;
        MessageBox.Show(msg2);
    }
}
```

The expected result should be an array of substrings like:

```
{ "TRX00 abcd 20150921 ", "TRX00 abcd 20150921 ", etc.. }
```

Comment: What is the expected result at all?

Comment: the expected result should be an array of substrings like:

{ "TRX00  abcd 20150921    ", "TRX00  abcd 20150921    ", etc.. }

Comment: trim then split on the 4 whitespaces `"    "` that delimit the groups.

Comment: Why doesn't it work well?

Comment: the number of chars inside each substring may be different each time.. the only part that is the same is the delimiter "TRX"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern in your code instead of `(TRX)`:

```
(?!^)(?=TRX)
```

It will split on TRX as long as it isn't at the start of the string and returns:

> TRX00  abcd 20150921
>
> TRX00  abcd 20150921
>
> TRX00  abcd 20150921

Comment: This regex pattern works like a charm! Thank you @dustmouse

Answer (score 0):

If you do actually treat "TRX" like a delimiter you can split the string using that, something like:

```
string msg = "TRX00  abcd 20150921    TRX00  abcd 20150921    TRX00  abcd 20150921    ";
string[] strings = msg.Split(new[] { "TRX" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                      .Select(x => "TRX" + x)
                      .Skip(1)
                      .ToArray();
```

You can then transform that delimited collection and add the "TRX" back on. Note I skip the first element (`Skip(1)`) as in this example that would just be am empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the desired strings are 19 characters long; you could truncate the beginning as long as the overall length of the input is larger as follows; however this solution is not very robust to a change of the input format, which makes it questionable.

```
List<String> Messages = new List<String>();
while (msg.length > 19)
{
    var Message = msg.Substring(19);
    Messages.Add(Message);
    msg = msg.Substring(20, msg.Length-1);
}
```

Comment: I count a length of 20, not 19.

Comment: the lenght can be different each time, the only part that is the same is the delimiter "TRX"